# Randomize Primary Keys Based on Existing Values

Tags: mysql, sql, shuffle

I have got an older database for which (at some really questionable and obscure reason I do not like to put too much on topic here) I want to randomize or shuffle the primary keys.

I right now have auto-increment fields in the Mysql database tables.

I have not many relations, those that exist are not defined as foreign keys. The relationships do not need to be preserved.

All I'm looking for is to take the current values of the primary keys and replace it with a random value out of those like:

```
ID := new(ID)
```

Where the new function returns a value from the set of all OLD ids with a 1:1 match. E.g.

```
2 := 3
3 := 2
```

But not

```
2 := 3
3 := 3
```

Is there a way to change the data in the database with (ideally) a single SQL query per table?

*Edit:* I do not have really strict requirements. Consider to have exclusive access to the database if it helps, including changing constraints on the primary key back and forth, e.g. alter the table, do the operation, alter the table to previous schema. It is also possible to add another column for the new (or old) PK value.

Comment: Only if you drop the primary key constraint and then recreate it.

Comment: @ypercube: That's an option. Changing the values can be done on a "snapshot" that is not "mounted". So next to the primary-key-changing queries nothing else queries the database.

Comment: There are really several parts - Is it possible to shuffle values in a column? Is it possible to shuffle values in a column using only set-based operations (i.e. not-programatically)? Is it possible to shuffle values in an auto-incremenet primary key column (using previous approach)?

Comment: @pst You can shuffle values using set-based operations but not when there is a unique constraint (not in MySQL that is).

Comment: @pst: Yes, about all these I'm not so sure. I can imagine that shuffling values in a column is something hard in SQL because it's not designed that way. Maybe the common question about how to randomize result orders can shed some light how to achieve that in a good way. If beign a primary key is a problem, that contraint could be "unmounted", consider to have exclusive access to the data. No need to make this more complicated as needed in my case.

Comment: @ypercube: Consider you could alter away the unique constraint (or alternatively) add a new column for the new ID which does not have the unique constraint. What would be the set operation? I don't know much about sets in Mysql. I only know "resultset" (which this probably is not) and then enum (but you probably do not mean that either).

Comment: @ypercube I'd vote for an answer showing how to shuffle values with a set-based operation. It seems like there would be some caveats/quirks with it (e.g. how to get a "ROW ID" in MySQL?)

Comment: Do you have foreign key constrants?

Comment: @wildplasser: Not really. I have some references, but they can be destroyed in the sense these do not need any updates. Would be okay if (so to say it's possible to find out the new/old value pair), but really not at all necessary *but* the reference must exist. E.g. just taking new numbers won't work.

Comment: Updating keys will cause referencing FKs to fail. But that's Ok? *I do have some references* ...? FYI: a real databases (with ON UPDATE CASCADE) would do the trick. Terribly slow, though.

Comment: There are no FKs defined in the database schema itself, so Mysql can not enforce them. The database is from a pre-FKs time, actually these relations exists, but in this concrete case I'm fine with breaking unless at least *some* (but not specifically these *originally same*) rows are referenced.

Comment: Which implies that you do have *natural* keys, and thus you could just as well drop the surrogates.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not that well with these terms: *natural keys* and *surrogates*. Actually PKs here are not natural keys, they are auto-increment fields. So not natural keys (, right?). About the surrogates: Actually I can drop them, but not the set. So, there will be a new surrogate value that is from the set of the old surrogate values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a scetch of the procedure. Create two temporary tables

```
CREATE TABLE temp_old
( ai INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, id INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (ai)
, INDEX old_idx (id, ai)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE temp_new
( ai INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, id INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (ai)
, INDEX new_idx (id, ai)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Copy the `id` values in different orders to the two tables (randomly in the 2nd table):

```
INSERT INTO temp_old
  (id)
SELECT id
FROM tableX 
ORDER BY id ;

INSERT INTO temp_new
  (id)
SELECT id
FROM tableX 
ORDER BY RAND() ;
```

Then we drop the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE tableX
  DROP PRIMARY KEY ;
```

to run the actual `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tableX AS t
  JOIN temp_old AS o
    ON o.id = t.id
  JOIN temp_new AS n
    ON n.ai = o.ai
SET t.id = n.id ;
```

Then recreate the primary key and drop the temp tables:

```
ALTER TABLE tableX
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id) ; 

DROP TABLE temp_old ;
DROP TABLE temp_new ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15769/1)**

Answer (score 3):

Here's a technique that creates a list of your ids in table order, along with a sequential number from 1, it also creates a list of your ids in a random order, along with a sequential number from 1. It then updates the ids based on matching the sequential number.

There are issues with the performance of order by rand(), (and it's randomness).

If your keys are already sequential starting from 1, you can simplify this.

```
Update
  Test as t
    Inner Join (
    Select 
      @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 as rank,
      t2.id
    From
      Test t2,
      (Select @rownum2:= 0) a1
  ) as o on t.id = o.id
    Inner Join (
      Select
        @rownum := @rownum + 1 as rank,
        t3.id
      From
        (Select id from Test order by Rand()) t3,
        (Select @rownum:= 0) a2
  ) as n on o.rank = n.rank
Set
  t.id = n.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f354/1

Comment: @ConradFrix But it doesn't work if there is a primary key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a stored procedure that would create a temporary table containing all of the ids, then you can loop over each record, replacing the id with an id from the temp table then removing that id from the temp table. I don't believe there is a way to do what you are talking about in a single query though.

Comment: Makes sense. I also can imagine adding another field so to keep the old primary key value next to the new one. May I ask you if you could share some SQL (no need to, just asking) showing how to create and populate such a temporary table? Does this really require a stored proecedure?

Comment: I know it is doable the way I described, although I am not entirely sure about the syntax. For my own learning, I am going to work on this for the next hour or so and see if I can make it work. I will share the result if I get it.

Comment: That would be great, but you don't have to do that just because I was asking. (well I know I sometimes do that as well if I find an interesting question, so I won't stop you either) ;)